# Passing in scope to db.collection.group

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Is it possible to pass a global context `db.collection.group`'s `keyf`?

```
{MongoClient} = require 'mongodb'

GLOBAL_VAR = 1

reducer = (obj, prev) -> prev.count += GLOBAL_VAR
initial = {count:0}

MongoClient.connect 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, db) ->
  throw err if err
  db.collection('orders').group [], {}, initial, reducer, (err, result) ->
    throw err if err
    console.log result
```

I get the following error

```
MongoError: exception: ReferenceError: GLOBAL_VAR is not defined at $group reduce setup:2
```

Comment: You really should show the code you are currently working with.

Comment: I haven't written the code yet because I wasn't able to find any documentation for exactly what I wanted to do, but I added an hypothetical example of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Does simply defining the `someGlobalFn` before the call to `.group()` not work?

Comment: No, the group function is run on the server not the client so it doesn't have access to the functions/variables. I have updated the question

Comment: I figured out a way to pass global variables, which is to send them through as the initial state

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables through as the initial state

```
{MongoClient} = require 'mongodb'

GLOBAL_VAR = 1

reducer = (obj, prev) -> prev.count += prev.GLOBAL_VAR
initial = {count: 0, GLOBAL_VAR}

MongoClient.connect 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, db) ->
  throw err if err
  db.collection('orders').group [], {}, initial, reducer, (err, result) ->
    throw err if err
    console.log result
```